# Bash command to check JDBC URL in Postgres database

Tags: bash, postgresql

How to check what is your JDBC URL on PostgreSQL database on a Ubuntu 19.04 machine. I mean if there is any command kindly provide me what it is:

I am trying to connect from the official document command:

```
jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/idempiere
```

but not getting any result.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check this URI adding the user:

```
psql -d postgresql://localhost:5432/idempiere?user=adempiere
```

If you don't add the user at the end it will assume your linux user.

pg_isready just checks if the server localhost is accepting connections on the port 5432 - it doesn't check the database.

Regards,

Carlos Ruiz

Answer (score 0):

If you want the connect string equivalent to the JDBC URI in your question, and you want to test if you can connect to the database, try

```
pg_isready -d postgresql://localhost:5432/idempiere
```